# Is it allowed to store the results that are returned from reverseGeocodeLocation() in database?

Tags: ios, reverse-geocoding, clgeocoder

I was wondering whether it is allowed to store address information that is returned from calling the `reverseGeocodeLocation` using the `CLGeocoder` class? In other words, if I would pass lat and long values to the `reverseGeocodeLocation` and store the results in my own database, would that violate any terms and condition guideline?

I have seen a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664586/reverse-geocoding-from-given-coordinates-not-current-location-but-manually-pro) here on Stack Overflow but nobody every mentioned anything about legal obligations.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not legal experts.  You should seek advice on this topic elsewhere.

Comment: Have you checked the terms & conditions? In any case, if you were to do that (store not only the result, but also the associated location) exhaustively for large sections of a map, you would run afoul of IP legislation in many countries, especially if you were to then provide a similar service. In other situations, you would be governed by the T&Cs you agreed to.

Comment: @Pekka웃 What does this have to do with Google? `CLGeocoder` is an Apple class.

Comment: @Jcaron Thank you for your answer. I think the safest bet is to look into terms & conditions as you recommended.
I believe the Google services such as Google places allows you to store the location code but thats pretty much it. You do not really have access or control over specific addresses.

Comment: Oh, apologies. I read „reverse geocoding“ and wrongly assumed Google.